# Jenkins kubernetes agent checkout scm not using configured key

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-kubernetes

I am getting errors using `checkout scm` in a pipeline, because of two issues.

The setup:

- Private Kubernetes cluster - 1 controller, 2 workers, on Ubuntu 20.04 VMs
- Jenkins running in Kubernetes pods
- Kubernetes plug-in to instantiate Jenkins build agents
- Private GIT server on the controller VM outside of the cluster, ssh access
- ssh private key for GIT configured in Jenkins credentials
- Jenkins project 'hello' configured to use this private GIT and associated ssh key
- Jenkinsfile (pipeline) to build

I want to use a simple `checkout scm` step in the Jenkinsfile.

**Problem 1** The build fails with `Host key verification failed.` because the Kubernetes agent pod doesn't have the GIT server in its `known_hosts`.

**Problem 2** If I force the controller cert into `known_hosts` (for example, hard-code an echo into Jenkinsfile, and then add a `git ls-remote` step), it fails with `Permission denied` because the configured ssh private key is not present in the agent pod.

I've found a workaround for both of these:

```
podTemplate(
...
{
  node(POD_LABEL) {
    stage('Checkout') {
      withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(
          credentialsId: 'private_git', 
          keyFileVariable: 'PRIVATE_GIT_KEY',
          passphraseVariable: '',
          usernameVariable: ''
      )]) {
        sh 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh'
        sh 'cp $PRIVATE_GIT_KEY ~/.ssh/id_rsa'
        sh '/usr/bin/ssh-keyscan -t rsa kube-master.cluster.dev >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
        sh 'chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.ssh'
        sh '/usr/bin/git ls-remote ssh://git@kube-master.cluster.dev:/git/hello.git'
      }
      checkout scm
    }
  ...
  }
}
```

What do I need to avoid this workaround and just use `checkout scm` like it is intended?

Example failure log:

```
Running on build-pod-xdh86-53wh7 in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/hello
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Checkout)
[Pipeline] checkout
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential private_git
Cloning the remote Git repository
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- ssh://git@kube-master.cluster.dev/git/hello.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable solution is to place the keys in Kubernetes secrets, and mount the secrets in the Jenkins pod.

On your controller machine:

1. Make a scratch user account and shell into it
2. Make the secret (typical ssh-keygen)
3. Add `id_rsa.pub` to the git server `authorized_users`
4. Connect to the git ssh once to produce `known_hosts`, for example

   `git ls-remote ssh://git@kube-master.cluster.dev:/git/hello.git`
5. Copy the scratch user's `~/.ssh/id_rsa` private key and `~/.ssh/known_hosts` files to a place where kubectl can read them, such as `/tmp/scratchuser`
6. Exit the scratch user account and delete it
7. `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /tmp/scratchuser/`
8. Add the `id_rsa` and `known_hosts` to Kubernetes, with a command like

   `kubectl create secret -n jenkins generic private-git --from-file=id_rsa=/tmp/scratchuser/.ssh/id_rsa --from-file=known_hosts=/tmp/scratchuser/.ssh/known_hosts`
9. Deploy Jenkins with a yaml containing some specific things:

   ```
   apiVersion: apps/v1
   kind: Deployment
   metadata:
     name: jenkins
     namespace: jenkins
   spec:
     ... your other options such as replicas, selector, etc ...
     template:
       metadata: ... your metadata section ...
       spec:
         securityContext:
           fsGroup: 1000
         containers:
         - name: jenkins
           image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
           ports:
             ... standard jenkins ports ...
           volumeMounts:
             - name: jenkins-vol
               mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
             - name: private-git-vol
               mountPath: "/var/jenkins_home/.ssh"
               readOnly: true
         volumes:
           - name: jenkins-vol
             ... your persistent volume details ...
           - name: private-git-vol
             secret:
               secretName: private-git
               defaultMode: 0600
         ... your other options such as dnsPolicy, etc. ...
   ```

The key points in the above yaml are `fsGroup` so that pod user `jenkins` can access the mounted secret volume, the `private-git-vol` mount to place the secret files into the `.ssh` path, and the `private-git-vol` definition that refers to the secret created with `kubectl` above.

One more hint. For a `Jenkinsfile` that instantiates build agent pods, see [Declarative Pipeline](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/). You might need to abandon `podTemplate()` and specify the agent pod yaml completely:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yamlFile 'KubernetesPod.yaml'
    }
  ... your build steps ...
}
```

and in `KubernetesPod.yaml`, include `jnlp` container (`jenkins/inbound-agent` image) with your own yaml instead of the Kubernetes plug-in. This will allow you to use `fsGroup` in the build agent, like described above for the Jenkins master.

Comment: Would this differ for GitHub and Bitbucket private repositories?

Comment: My scenario here is for a fully private Kubernetes cluster, where I am running Kubernetes bare metal and hosting git myself - for a highly secure cluster that can't be accessed on the internet. For something like github, you might be able to learn something from above, but you should be able to find a different path that is not this complicated.